# A formula text field to see if candidate has been approved

Tags: formula, custom-field, checkbox

I have a checkbox field named "Approval" that is checked and not checked when creating a candidate record to see if they have been approved. What I'm trying to do is create a formula text field named “Custom Approval Message” that will dynamically display this:

i. “Record not yet approved” – When a candidate's test record has not yet been approved.

ii. “Record has been approved” – When a candidate's test record is approved.

My main question is how to achieve this using a custom formula field. I've tried using if statements to complete this but don't know how to make the message appear

I'm very new to using salesforce and cannot figure out how to do this. Any help appreciated

Comment: This is in salesforce by the way

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far. Even if it doesn't work, it helps to narrow down the issue and help people tailor their answers to your specific issue. If you have some programming knowledge already, then the [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.customize_functions.htm) documentation should be helpful.

Comment: Now that you've registered, this is a duplicate of [How do I use a formula text field to display in a record whether a candidate has been approved or not, based off a checkbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381929/how-do-i-use-a-formula-text-field-to-display-in-a-record-whether-a-candidate-has)